# Not able to center content using the Box component in MaterialUI and React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Box component from MaterialUI in react and want to be able to center the child component within the page. However, I am unable to do so. I have tried all possible parameters including `alignItems` `justifyContent` etc.

This is how I export the component

```
export const FeaturesScroll = () => {

  return (
    <Box alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" sx={{ bgcolor: 'background.paper', maxWidth: 1200, justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This component is being called within a `div` component as shown below

```
export const Home = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <HeroSection/>
      <BodySection1/>
      <BodySection2/>
      <FeaturesScroll/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use display:flex property for alignItems and justifyContent to work

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was missing that property and adding it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sx={{ display: 'flex' ,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}`
you can not use alignItems and justifyContent as a prop

```
   <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' ,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1" style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </Typography>
        </Box>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. While this solves the problem the answer is not completely correct. As per the documentation here https://mui.com/components/box/#system-props  "As a CSS utility component, the Box also supports all system properties. You can use them as prop directly on the component." I think the `display = flex` was what I was missing hence I am accepting the other answer.